# Multiplying radio button values by a textbox value in javacsript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I'm pretty new to programming but I have a HTML form which includes 5 radio buttons the user can select from and a textbox the user needs to write a number into. I want to multiply the value of the selected radio button by the value written into the textbox when the user presses a calculate button. I have been trying to do this with a script in the HTML form but I can't get it to work. Could anybody help Please???

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Sorry but it wasnt being taken off hold so I just wanted to get rid of it

Comment: @JoeCole2233 you can delete it then

Comment: it says i cant because other people have answered it. @gsquaredxc

Comment: i thought mods would know how this website worked lol @gsquaredxc

Answer (score 1):

First you will want to get a reference to the text input, then you will want to get the selected radio button which can be done with a query selector. You will then you just need to multiply the two together.

Here is the most basic way to do this:

```
let input = document.querySelector('input[type=number]')
let checked = document.querySelector('[name=radio]:checked')

let result = parseFloat(input.value) * parseFloat(checked.value)
```

Here is a working example:

```js
// Get reference to the input field
let input = document.querySelector('input[type=number]')
let output = document.querySelector('output')

// Create radio button event listeners
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]')).forEach(input => {
  // When the radio changes recalculate
  input.addEventListener('change', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    calculate()
  })
})

// And the textbox event listner
// When the value changes recalculate
input.addEventListener('input', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  calculate()
})

// Make calculation
function calculate() {
  // Get the checked radio
  let checked = document.querySelector('[type=radio]:checked')
  // Get its value. If no radio is checked default to 0
  let value = checked ? checked.value : 0
  // Multiply the radio time the text box
  let result = parseFloat(value) * parseFloat(input.value)
  // Set the output value use 0 if the result is not a number
  output.value = !isNaN(result) ? result : 0
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="radio"> 1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" value="2" name="radio"> 2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" value="3" name="radio"> 3</label> &times;
  <input type="number" id="txt" placeholder="Enter a number"> =
  <output>0</output>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you in creating logic similar to what you asked. Thank you.

```js
function testcalc(){
var val1= parseInt($("input[name='multiplier']:checked")[0].value);
var val2= parseInt($("#testinput")[0].value);
$('#testanswer').text(val1*val2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="testinput" value="0">
<input type="radio" name="multiplier" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="multiplier" value="3">3
<input type="radio" name="multiplier" value="4">4
<input type="radio" name="multiplier" value="5">5
<input type="radio" name="multiplier" value="6">6
<button onClick="testcalc()">Calculate</button>
<p><span id="testanswer"></span></p>
```